# Energy Consumption in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I would like to analyse the electrical energy consumed by a furnace in a conveyor system. Is there a method or specific function to do this using Anylogic?

I've found little material surrounding this, so pointing in the right direction would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer: There is no build-in functionality. But you can easily do this yourself.

If you want very high accuracy, you should check system dynamics (but this slows your model quite a bit).

If you want a simple approach, I can think of this:

1. create a variable `elecConsumptionPerMin` in your furnace agent
2. create an event `consumeElec` in your furnace that cyclically (every minute) adds to the total furnace consumption (another variable)
3. on model startup, ideally set `myFurnace.consumeElec.suspend()`
4. when the furnace starts producing, call ´myFurnace.consumeElec.resume()` to start consuming enegery

Obviously, you can refine this to the nth degree and you might also want to experiment with state charts. But this is the simple approach